# What is the "left" and "right" table in an intermediate SQL Join?

Tags: sql-server, join

```
SELECT * FROM Table a
INNER JOIN Table b on a.ID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN Table c on a.ID = c.ID
LEFT JOIN Table d on c.Something = d.Something -- which is left vs right
LEFT JOIN Table e on b.Something = e.Something -- which is left vs right
```

This is potentially a silly question, but so that I can remove this brain blockage, which table is the "left" one and which table is the "right" one in my last two joins? Is this determined by which one is first in the list in correspondence with the "on" ? I can write the queries and ensure proper results, but just having trouble understanding it on a technical level... when dealing with intermediate tables like the above example.

Comment: Why the down-vote? This is an area of confusion for a lot of people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN Table d on c.Something = d.Something
```

c is left and d is right.

```
LEFT JOIN Table e on b.Something = e.Something
```

b is left and e is right.

The table you're joining to the query (in this case d and e) is the right so whatever key from the previous query you're joining with is from the left table(c and b).

Comment: So the left is whichever one is "first" in the list, row by row?

Comment: Check edit and explanation. I realized it needed explaining about 5 milliseconds after I hit "Post".

Comment: Ok so to be super clear, the "on" specifies what columns to join, and whichever table precedes has already been joined previously within this "on" is the "left" table. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Whatever you included in the query before that join counts as "left". So any columns from any previous tables that were joined are "left" as far as your current join is concerned.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine that each time you add a table you are building a horizontal hierarchy.

In this case you started with `FROM Table A` so that becomes the top level of the hierarchy (sitting on the far left).

When you `INNER JOIN Table b`, it becomes a second level and sits to the Right of Table A. In this join table A is left and table B is right.

The same happens with your `LEFT JOIN`'s.

[image]

It's also worth noting that the order of columns in the `ON` clause of the join doesn't matter.

```
LEFT JOIN Table d on d.Something = c.Something
LEFT JOIN Table e on e.Something = b.Something
```

means the same as:

```
LEFT JOIN Table d on c.Something = d.Something
LEFT JOIN Table e on b.Something = e.Something
```

Because the order in which the tables are added affects which side of the join they are on and not the order of the `ON` clause.